# Problems with maxrregcount and dynamic parallelism

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I am trying to estimate the effect of restricting register usage on achieved occupancy of the application. While running my experiments, when I tried to restrict the number of registers of cdpBezierTessellation application found in Nvidia samples, I got an error.

Flag added to nvcc: -maxrregcount 16

```
Error: nvlink error : entry function '_Z21computeBezierLinesCDPP10BezierLinei' with max regcount of 16 calls function 'cudaMalloc' with regcount of 18
```

I don't understand exactly why this is happening. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: did you read [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/821348/cuda-programming-and-performance/launch-bounds-directive-not-respected-by-__device__-functions-implemented-in-other-files/post/4494586/#4494586) ?

Comment: There is nothing to help. The linker is helpfully telling you what you are trying to do is impossible because the kernel calls a pre-compiled device function with a larger register footprint than your `maxrregcount` setting allows.

Comment: I understand that there is nothing that I can do. I am asking help to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 6):

As commenters have said, the linker error message is very clear in telling you what is happening. You are trying to compile your kernel (`computeBezierLinesCDP()`) telling it that it may use a maximum of 16 registers, however then when you come to the link step (which is after compilation) the linker finds that one of the functions you are calling from within the kernel (`cudaMalloc()`) uses 18 registers. This is a constraint the linker is *clearly* unable to satisfy!

Since you cannot reduce the number of registers used by `cudaMalloc()` (since it's a pre-compiled library routine), you need to increase your register limit.

If you really need to constrain your kernel to 16 registers then you would need to avoid calling `cudaMalloc()` (and any other routine that uses more registers). You may be able to avoid allocating memory from within your kernel by pre-allocating from the host.

Comment: I understand that part. But if I don't use Dynamic Parallelism and try to restrict the register usage for cudaMalloc at 16 registers, it compiles and links without any errors. The part that I don't understand is that why would the linker fail when I use cudaMalloc in this setting.